# passing a var from Razor MVC to JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of items, and all of them will have a "click here for further info" link.  With this link, I want to open a modal popup and display the details inside it.  My problem is, how can I pass the id to the relevant modal popup.

At the moment I have the following code :-

Every item in the list will have the following:-

```
<a href="#" class="modal_link" data-id="@item.ExpId">Click here for more info.</a>
```

and in my jquery I have the following :-

```
    var id = $(".modal_link").attr("data-id");
alert(id);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal_block').click(function (e) {
        $('#tn_select').empty();
        $('.modal_part').hide();
    });

    $('.modal_link').click(function (e) {
        $('.modal_part').show();
        var context = $('#tn_select').load('/Experience/ShowExpDetail?id=' + id, function () {
            initSelect(context);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });

});
```

however the id is always undefined.

How can I pass this var?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: You have place that piece of code in document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the `id` of each link to be supplied when it's clicked, you need to use a self-reference, which you get from `this`, like so:

```
$('.modal_link').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal_part').show();

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var context = $('#tn_select').load('/Experience/ShowExpDetail?id=' + id, function () {
        initSelect(context);
    });
});
```

Your `load()` call doesn't feel entirely right to me, but I'd have to see the rest of the script to know...

Comment: the load() is done through a PartialView inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

Just move these lines 
`var id = $(".modal_link").attr("data-id");
alert(id);`
inside
`$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: Inside the `click` event, actually, but close.

Comment: Does it matters? Anyway result will be the same :)

Comment: Yes, it does matter, and no, the results aren't the same.

Comment: you are right Morpheus, I though it did not matter if it was inside or not

Comment: I could, but I don't need to. It's plain common sense that a variable that is set once at document.ready isn't going to accurately reflect the value of the clicked instance.

Comment: @TiesonT. I agreed with you til you said it is plain common sense, not for a beginner it isn't, moving from windows forms to web can be a big leap considering the change in statelessness.

Comment: @Morpheus There is more than one `.modal_link` in the page, and this would fix the `id` value at the id of the first `.modal_link`.

Comment: @JLRishe, you are right :) I didn't paid the attention to the question. Need coffee to wake up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.modal_link').click(function (e) {

 alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $('.modal_part').show();
        var context = $('#tn_select').load('/Experience/ShowExpDetail?id=' + id, function () {
            initSelect(context);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```